# Visual Studio 2013 EDMX set db column limit

Tags: database, limit, visual-studio-2013

I would like to know if there is any way to set in Visual Studio 2013 in an .edmx the maximum size for a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just select the field in the edmx, go to the Properties (F4 usually) and enter the Max Length

[image: EDMX Max Length Property]

Comment: I watched a bunch of times at this list of properties and it seems I skipped it every time. Thank you!